# Add two possible paths with "window.location.href " under the same condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, relative-path, window.location

I created an interactive tree diagram using the library d3.js and I'm now trying to add the functionality that whenever you click on a node, it redirects you to the page of this element (corresponding to a node).

Previously, I only had elements of type "product" and used this function:

```
function clack(d) {
  if (d.name != "Product Catalog"){
    window.location.href = "http://1XX.XX.1.XX/App/redirect?entity_type=product&field_name=itemId&field_value=" + d.id;
  }
}
```

And it worked perfectly!

HOWEVER, I now added another type of elements called "risk_coverages" that are the children of the products, but want to be redirected to the path of those two elements.

In fact, the function for my new entity type "risk_coverages" only would be:

```
 function clack(d) {
  if (d.name != "Product Catalog"){
    window.location.href = "http://1XX.XX.1.XX/App/redirect?entity_type=risk_coverages&field_name=itemId&field_value=" + d.id;
  }
}
```

My problem is that I don't know how to make the condition for:

IF "entity_type=product&field_name=itemId&field_value=" + d.id , THEN redirect me to my product page

OR

IF "entity_type=risk_coverages&field_name=itemId&field_value=" + d.id , THEN redirect me to my risk coverage page

In English, it would be:

IF it's a product, then look for this product and display its page

OR

IF it's a risk coverage, then look for this risk coverage and display its page

I hope I was clear enough.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks a lot,

Allan

Here is the full code:

```
<style>

.node, .clickable {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.node text {
  font: 100% sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
Click on a node to expand the tree. Click on a product name to navigate to the product's detail page.
<tree>

<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 140, bottom: 20, left: 120},
    width =  2200 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 1000 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

var svg = d3.select("tree").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.json("/App/assets/tree.json", function(error, flare) {
  root = flare;
  root.x0 = height / 2;
  root.y0 = 0;

  function collapse(d) {
    if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d._children.forEach(collapse);
      d.children = null;
    }
  }

  root.children.forEach(collapse);
  update(root);
});

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
      links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 250; });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
      ;

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; })
      .on("click", click)      
      ;

  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6)
      .attr("class", "hyper").on("click", clack);

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 4.5)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
      .remove();

  nodeExit.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6);

  nodeExit.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      })
      .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}

  //collapse function
  function collapse(d) {
    if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d._children.forEach(collapse);
      d.children = null;
    }
  }

// Toggle children on click.
  function click(d) {
    if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d.children = null;
    } else {
      d.children = d._children;
      d._children = null;
    }

  if (d.parent)  {
    //console.log(d.parent.children);
    //collapse(d.parent.children[0]);
    d.parent.children.forEach(function(element) {
      if (d !== element) {
        collapse(element);
      }
    });
  }

  update(d);
}

function clack(d) {
  if (d.name != "Product Catalog"){
    window.location.href = "http://1XX.XX.1X.XX/App/redirect?entity_type=risk_coverages&field_name=itemId&field_value=" + d.id;
  }
}


</script>
```

`

Comment: You could put a `data` attribute on the node which specifies its type (either `product` or `risk_coverage`) then append that value to the URL. That way you can use a single function for all types of node

Comment: Guys, I _think_ the point is that he doesn't know how to distinguish which page to load based on the URL. (The problem isn't in generating the url, but in reading / acting on it)

Comment: How do you get the `d.id`? Can't you get the `entity_type` the same way?

Comment: How does your object `d` looks like? What kind of properties does it have?

Comment: Hi, yes Cerbus you're right.

Comment: The problem is not lying in the d.id nor the entity type. When I run either one of the two commands, the function is working perfectly (either for risk_coverages or products) with those two functions. My problem is that I don't know how to include a condition OR in it. To have: Look for products OR RiskCoverages

Comment: Thanks a lot guys

Comment: Basically you want the function to always look for both entity_type=product and entity_type=risk_coverages?

Comment: @Z-Bone, yes exactly

Comment: @AllanLC since you are trying to redirect to a page, why not change the logic of your backend code to know how to handle 2 arguments as well? For example: `http://1XX.XX.1.XX/App/redirect?entity_type[]=risk_coverages&entity_type[]=product`

Comment: @Z-Bone I've tried but doesn't seems to work... I'm not an expert but is there any way of adding an "OR condition" where the path is?

Comment: @AllanLC You cant redirect to 2 pages in the same time. You can just get the data using ajax with no need to redirect. Why not post the relevant part of your backend code and lets see what we can do. What language do you use?

Comment: @Z-Bone: Here is my code,

Comment: @AllanLC: I meant your backend code (e.g.: PHP, Node.js etc..). Because the server is the one that looks up the entity types and returns results. We want to edit the server code to be able to take 2 entity types at once and display results in a single redirect

Comment: @Z-Bone Ahh yes. Unfortunately I cannot (company doesn't allow me)... Finally I just created another function: Ugly but working... Thanks a lot for your help and happy new year!!

Comment: @AllanLC Cheers